# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation - Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to update an Azure Active Directory Application but I get the error message " Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" as shown below. I have full admin access and I have given the api both delegated and application permissions as shown below and  user administrator role as well.  I have done search on permissions and roles but still cant get it working.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of my permissions configurations.

[image]

Comment: Did you accepted grant admin consent after assigning API permission?

Comment: Yes! Admin consent was granted after assigning API permission.

Comment: Which role you are belongs to and what are you trying to update?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I am the Global Administrator. I have created sample web AAD app successfully and in the process of deploying it, however, before deployment is complete I need to update the AAD app using by running this  script  .\UpdateApps.ps1 -armConfig .\ARMParameters.json -newAppsConfig .\NewApps.json the instructions are found here   https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-add-in-saas-monetization-sample/blob/master/Deployment/DeploymentGuide.MD )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run the Microsoft Graph Powershell `Get-MgApplication`, you need to login it with the command like below, including the `Application.Read.All` delegated permission.

```
Connect-Graph -Scopes "User.Read","Application.Read.All"
```

It will open a window, then you need to enter the code authenticate, select the account which is the `Global admin`, select `Consent on behalf of your organization` option,  click the `Accept` like below.

[image]

After login, run `Get-MgApplication`, it will work fine.

[image]

---

**In addition**, actually the Microsoft Graph Powershell comamnds call different Graph APIs, to run different commands, you need to `Connect-Graph` with different permissions, e.g. if you want to run `Update-MgApplication`, you need to add `Application.ReadWrite.All`, to run `Get-MgGroup`, you need to add `Group.Read.All`.

Answer (score 0):

For entitlement management you may need to run the following cmdlet:

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All"

And if you need to add or remove groups scoped to access packages then run:

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All","Group.ReadWrite.All"